# Posts not correctly sorting

Tags: wordpress

I have sorted my posts in the wordpress dashboard but that is not what is showing in the index page no matter what theme I use

This is what shows in the dashboard - all posts age

[Image of ordering of posts Dasboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wI0fN.png)

As you can see *Women who got back their rights is the last post* in the dashboard

But in the site itself I see:

[Ordering of posts in the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jpuQ.png)

Where *Women who got back their rights is the last post* is the second post rather than the last.

How do i fix this.

*To take a closer look go to* *http://theblossominglady.website*

Comment: Where your blog render php code?

Comment: Can remove sticky post and then check

Comment: Without an additional plugin, the sorting of posts on the backend view (other than making a post sticky) will have no impact on how posts are ordered on the frontend.

Comment: @So what do i do